# How to fix the authentication from eks cluster to Hashicorp Vault outside of the cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault

I have a Hashicorp Vault Cluster created under some URL outside of my EKS Cluster, as I'm using it for multiple clusters. Now I want that the EKS Cluster is reading some secrets from my vaults and using them inside some of my code creation. I installed the vault-injector in the specific namespace that I'm using and and it already starting a vault-agent-init pod, as it should. My problem is now that the authentication is apparently not working and I don't know where the problem could be.

My deployment.yaml file has the following annotations:

```
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-cache-enable: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "<role-name>"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-database-connect.conf: "<engine>/<path>/db"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-database-connect.conf: |
          {{`{{- with secret "<engine>/<path>/db" -}}
          username: {{ .Data.username }} 
          password: {{ .Data.password }}
          {{- end -}}`}}
```

My policy in the vault is defined as followed with a name "test" for example:

```
path "<engine>/<path>/*" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

Now I ran

```
vault auth enable kubernetes
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/<role-name> \
      bound_service_account_names=<sa-name> \
      bound_service_account_namespaces=<my-namespace> \
      policies=test \
      ttl=24h
```

I also created a ServiceAccount in the same namespace with some name "". Running the deployment is stuck on the vault-agent-init container with the following error message:

2023-10-13T14:22:25.581Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2023-10-13T15:24:50.800Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Put "https:///v1/auth/kubernetes/login": dial tcp : connect: connection refused" backoff=4m44.42s

Can someone please help me, figure out the issue and what I might have missed in this setup?

Comment: I guess I missed to add the kubernetes api endpoint and certificate to vault. I did this now with the following command:

vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
    kubernetes_host="https:/xxxxx.xx.xx.eks.amazonaws.com" \
    kubernetes_ca_cert=some-cert.crt 

but I guess I still have to add the token reviewer:
token_reviewer_jwt="<your reviewer service account JWT>"

but I dont understand at all, how I do that with an external running vault and an eks cluster. Can someone describe this process to me?